# Locking cell E15 and E16 based on value is "Yes" or "No" selected in drop-down at E14

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I want to lock cell E15 and E16 if value is selected as "No" in dropdown at E14 cell. How to implement this using VBA Macros

Comment: You would use a `WorkSheet_Change` event to detect a change, check if it's E14 and act accordingly.  There is a wealth of examples out there of how to do this just a search away. You'll probably want to research a Worksheet protection's `UserInterfaceOnly` property too.

Comment: It is unclear what you have tried and what the issue was with your attempt. Please [edit] your question to include your attempt with a detailde error description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.